# How to retrieve the state to be consumed in corda

Tags: corda

I need to update a state in Corda, once after it is created. I am using LinearState class for this, which have a LinearID field of type UniqueIdentifier. I am facing an issue in how to pass the UniqueIdentifier of the state to be consumed to the constructor of the UpdateFlow in the node's terminal. The code for my Update Flow is as follows:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
public static class UpdateOffer extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
        private final ProgressTracker.Step GENERATING_TRANSACTION = new ProgressTracker.Step("Generating transaction.");
        private final ProgressTracker.Step ADDING_NEW_OFFER = new ProgressTracker.Step("Adding the New Offer State.");
        private final ProgressTracker.Step VERIFYING_TRANSACTION = new ProgressTracker.Step("Verifying contract constraints.");
        private final ProgressTracker.Step SIGNING_TRANSACTION = new ProgressTracker.Step("Signing transaction with our private key.");
        private final ProgressTracker.Step GATHERING_SIGS = new ProgressTracker.Step("Gathering the counterparty's signature.") {
            @Override
            public ProgressTracker childProgressTracker() {
                return CollectSignaturesFlow.Companion.tracker();
            }
        };
        private final ProgressTracker.Step FINALISING_TRANSACTION = new ProgressTracker.Step("Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.") {
            @Override
            public ProgressTracker childProgressTracker() {
                return FinalityFlow.Companion.tracker();
            }
        };

        private final ProgressTracker progressTracker = new ProgressTracker(
                GENERATING_TRANSACTION,
                ADDING_NEW_OFFER,
                VERIFYING_TRANSACTION,
                SIGNING_TRANSACTION,
                GATHERING_SIGS,
                FINALISING_TRANSACTION
        );


        @Override
        public ProgressTracker getProgressTracker() {
            return progressTracker;
        }

        //Class Variables
        private final UniqueIdentifier linearID;
        private final String sender;
        private final String receiver;
        private final String policyID;
        private final double faceValue;
        private final double offeredAmount;

        public UpdateOffer(UniqueIdentifier linearID, String sender, String receiver, String policyID, double faceValue, double offeredAmount) {
            this.linearID = linearID;
            this.sender = sender;
            this.receiver = receiver;
            this.policyID = policyID;
            this.faceValue = faceValue;
            this.offeredAmount = offeredAmount;
        }

        @Override
        public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
            List<UUID> listOfLinearIds = new ArrayList<>();
            listOfLinearIds.add(linearID.getId());
            QueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(null, listOfLinearIds);

            // 2. Get a reference to the inputState data that we are going to settle.
            Vault.Page results = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(OfferState.class, queryCriteria);
            StateAndRef inputStateAndRefToTransfer = (StateAndRef) results.getStates().get(0);
            OfferState inputStateToTransfer = (OfferState) inputStateAndRefToTransfer.getState().getData();


            AccountService accountService = getServiceHub().cordaService(KeyManagementBackedAccountService.class);
            //Owner Account
            AccountInfo lspAccountInfo = accountService.accountInfo(sender).get(0).getState().getData();
            PublicKey lspKey = subFlow(new NewKeyForAccount(lspAccountInfo.getIdentifier().getId())).getOwningKey();
            AnonymousParty lspAccount = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(lspAccountInfo));

            //Insurance Company Account
            AccountInfo sellerAccountInfo = accountService.accountInfo(receiver).get(0).getState().getData();
            AnonymousParty sellerAccount = subFlow(new RequestKeyForAccount(sellerAccountInfo));

            final Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);
            final OfferState output = new OfferState(inputStateToTransfer.getLinearId(), lspAccount,sellerAccount,policyID,faceValue,offeredAmount, true);

            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(GENERATING_TRANSACTION);
            TransactionBuilder builder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);

            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(ADDING_NEW_OFFER);
            builder.addInputState(inputStateAndRefToTransfer);
            builder.addOutputState(output,OfferContract.ID);
            builder.addCommand(new OfferContract.Commands.Send(), Arrays.asList(lspKey,sellerAccount.getOwningKey()));

            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(SIGNING_TRANSACTION);
            builder.verify(getServiceHub());
            SignedTransaction locallySignedTx = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(builder,Arrays.asList(getOurIdentity().getOwningKey(),lspKey));

            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(GATHERING_SIGS);
            FlowSession session  = initiateFlow(sellerAccountInfo.getHost());
            List<TransactionSignature> accountToMoveToSignature = (List<TransactionSignature>) subFlow(new CollectSignatureFlow(locallySignedTx,
                    session,sellerAccount.getOwningKey()));
            SignedTransaction signedByCounterParty = locallySignedTx.withAdditionalSignatures(accountToMoveToSignature);

            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(FINALISING_TRANSACTION);
            return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(signedByCounterParty, session));
        }
 }
```

Can anyone help me with this? I have been stuck here for more than a week now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Instead of having a `UniqueIdentifier` input parameter in your flow's constructor, use a `String`:

  ```java
  public UpdateOffer(String linearID...
  ```
- Then inside your flow you can query like this:

  ```java
  LinearStateQueryCriteria linearCriteria = new LinearStateQueryCriteria()
                      .withExternalId(Collections.singletonList(linearId));
  ```
- Since your input parameter is now a `String`, you can easily pass it from the terminal.